# Sum of the bits in Java

Tags: java, bit

sorry Friends i did a mistake. I have did this mistake again. am really very sorry.

this is the Issue.

I have a time range like

```
int Starttime = 2 which mean(02:00)
int enttime =  8 which mean(08:00)
```

i want time in sum of bits, 
example

```
     00:00 1  
     01:00 2    
     02:00 4  -----
     03:00 8   R
     04:00 16  a
     05:00 32  n
     06:00 64  g
     07:00 128 e
     08:00 256 -----
```

and soo on till 23:00

so i need totalRange = 256+128+64+32+16+8+4 ;

it should be like this 
sorry again.

Thanks

Comment: You should rephrase your question, obviously nobody really understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table indicates that you want to map the hour value of a time to an integer value using this function:

```
int value = (int) Math.pow(2, hourValue);
```

or, in other words, 00:00h will map to 2<sup>0</sup>, 12:00h to 2<sup>12</sup> and so on.

Now if you have need the sum of start and endtime, you can simple use the function from above and add the values:

```
int totalrange = (int) Math.pow(2, starttime) + (int) Math.pow(2, endtime);
```

Now if you have starttime=2 and endtime=23, this will give a result (written in binary):

```
01000000 00000000 00000100
```

---

shamelessly adapting [polygenelubricants much faster solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555022/sum-of-the-bits-in-java/3555066#3555066):

```
int totalrange = (1 << starttime) + (1 << endtime);
```

This works, because 2<sup>i</sup> is equal to (1 << i).

Comment: `Math.pow(2, x)` should be replaced by bitwise operations

Comment: Im not sure it should. Math.pow(2,x) is clear and obvious - bitwise operations are not. Using the function also makes a semantic statement as to the purpose of the line. Using bitwise operations smacks of PO.

Comment: Even supposing that Java programmers can confused by the meaning of something like `1 << hour` to mean "2 to the power of..." it is still the right thing to do in this instance because what is wanted *is* a simple bit shift.  This is evidenced by the fact that you had to explain that a bit shift can be implemented by raising the bits to a power of two.

Answer (score 2):

```
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2+24)); // 11010
```

This uses the [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) method. There's also [`toHexString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29), [`toOctalString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29), and a [`toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) with variable radix.

If you need the string to be zero-padded to a specific width, you can write something simple like this:

```
static String binaryPadded(int n, int width) {
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    return "00000000000000000000000000000000"
                .substring(0, width - s.length()) + s;
}

//...
System.out.println(binaryPadded(2+24, 8)); // 00011010
```

There are different ways to zero pad a string to a fixed width, but this will work for any `int` value.

For hexadecimal or octal, you can use [formatting string](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) instead:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%04X", 255)); // 00FF
```

---

The specification isn't very clear, but it looks like you want this mapping:

> `0 -> 1`
>   `1 -> 2`
>   `2 -> 4`
>   `3 -> 8`
>   `4 -> 16`
>   `:`
>   `i -> 2`<sup>i</sup>

In that case, your mapping is from `i` to `(1 << i)` (the `<<` is the [bitwise left-shift operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19)).

```
    System.out.println(
        (1 << 2) + (1 << 4)
    ); // 20
```

Note that depending on what is it that you're trying to do, you may also consider using a [`java.util.BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead.

---

#### `BitSet` demonstration

This may be completely off-the-mark, but assuming that you're doing some sort of interval arithmetics, then `BitSet` may be the data structure for you ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/W1y58)):

```
import java.util.BitSet;
//...

static String interval(BitSet bs) {
    int i = bs.nextSetBit(0);
    int j = bs.nextClearBit(i);
    return String.format("%02d:00-%02d:00", i, j);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BitSet workTime = new BitSet();
    workTime.set(9, 17);
    System.out.println(interval(workTime));
    // 09:00-17:00

    BitSet stackOverflowTime = new BitSet();
    stackOverflowTime.set(10, 20);
    System.out.println(interval(stackOverflowTime));
    // 10:00-20:00

    BitSet busyTime = new BitSet();
    busyTime.or(workTime);
    busyTime.or(stackOverflowTime);
    System.out.println(interval(busyTime));
    // 09:00-20:00
}
```

Note that methods like [`nextSetBit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29) and [`nextClearBit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextClearBit%28int%29) makes it easy to find empty/occupied time slots. You can also do [`intersect`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#intersects%28java.util.BitSet%29), [`or`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#or%28java.util.BitSet%29), [`and`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#and%28java.util.BitSet%29), etc.

This simple example only finds the first interval, but you can make this more sophisticated and do various arithmetics on non-contiguous time intervals.

Comment: Thanks that worked,, Sorry for unclear question. But thanks a lot. it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.toBinaryString(i)
```

Returns a string representation of the integer argument as anunsigned integer in base 2.

Comment: sorry, What i want is not in bit values 

I want 02:00 + 04:00 which mean 4 + 16 = 20  

I want the numberical value of that bit like 20. 

     00:00 1  
     01:00 2  
     02:00 4  
     03:00 8  
     04:00 16 
and so on

Answer (score 1):

To compute the length of the time-interval, you have to do

```
int totalrange = endtime - starttime;
```

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
int startTime = 2;
int endTime = 24;
int range = endTime - startTime;

System.out.println(range + " can be expressed as the following sum:");
for (int size = 1; range > 0; size <<= 1, range >>= 1)
    if ((range & 1) != 0)
        System.out.format("+ %02d:00%n", size);
```

**Output:**

```
22 can be expressed as the following sum:
+ 02:00
+ 04:00
+ 16:00
```